# Print time in C initially and at the end of doing sleep

Tags: c, date, datetime, time

I'm trying to print the date two times:

```
char *init_time = getTime();
// Do something and sleep 5 seconds
char *end = getTime();
printf("train 2 started at %s and arrived at %s\n", init_time, end);
```

The get time:

```
char* getTime(){
    time_t result;
    result = time(NULL);
    return asctime(localtime(&result));
}
```

Why is the result printed the same?

Comment: Again and again, we get people who will not read up the function they are using, before asking a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the asctime man page:

> The asctime() function converts the broken-down time value tm into
> a null-terminated string with the same format as ctime().  The return
> value points to  a  statically  allocated    string  which  might  be
> overwritten by subsequent calls to any of the date and time functions.
> The asctime_r() function does the same, but stores the string in a
> user-supplied    buffer which should have room for at least 26 bytes.

In other word, your second call to asctime stores its result in the same buffer where the result of the first call was stored.

Copy the result somewhere if you want to keep it for later use, or print it as soon as you get it, or use *asctime_r*.